# Finding a sick day before or after a vacation and it might be across a weekend

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

This is what I'm trying to sort out and any direction would be appreciated.

- Employee 6 took a vacation day on Friday 08/16/2019 but called in Sick on Thursday 08/15/2019.
- Employee 10 took Vacation Monday through Thursday 08/12/2019-08/15/2019 then called in Sick on 08/16/2019
- Employee 14 took vacation Monday through Friday 08/05/2019-08/09/2019 then called in Sick the following Monday 08/12/2019.
- Employee 23 called in sick on Friday 08/02/2019 before starting vacation on 08/05/2019 – 08/09/2019.

I do have code that looks for a pattern, in this case looking for 3 consecutive sick days to make sure it isn't an FMLA case but I can't sort out the logic to check for the SK day before or after a PT day.

```
DECLARE @var_StartDate DATETIME = '10/28/2018' -- Set the start date
DECLARE @var_EndDate DATETIME = '10/26/2019';  --Set the end date

--:OUT"C:\Data\3_consecutive_Sick_Days.csv"

SELECT 
        EMPLOYEEID
       ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),MIN(ABSENCEDATE),101) AS Absence_Start
       ,LEFT(DATENAME(DW,MIN(ABSENCEDATE)),3) AS Start_DOW
       ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),MAX(ABSENCEDATE),101) AS Absence_End
       ,LEFT(DATENAME(DW,MAX(ABSENCEDATE)),3) AS End_DOW
       ,COUNT(EMPLOYEEID) AS Count
       ,PAYCODENAME

FROM (SELECT A.EMPLOYEEID, A.ABSENCEDATE,A.PAYCODENAME,SUM(COL) OVER(PARTITION BY EMPLOYEEID, PAYCODENAME ORDER BY ABSENCEDATE) AS GRP
      FROM (SELECT A.*,
            CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,LAG(ABSENCEDATE) OVER(PARTITION BY EMPLOYEEID, PAYCODENAME ORDER BY ABSENCEDATE),ABSENCEDATE)=1 
                --OR (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,[ABSENCEDATE])=2 AND DATEPART(WEEKDAY,LAG([ABSENCEDATE]) OVER(PARTITION BY EMPLOYEEID,PAYCODENAME ORDER BY ABSENCEDATE))=6)
            THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS COL
            FROM VP_ABSENCE A
                      WHERE   ABSENCEDATE BETWEEN @var_StartDate AND @var_EndDate
                              AND PAYCODENAME IN ('SK')
                              AND A.TIMEINSECONDS > 0

                ) A ) A

GROUP BY EMPLOYEEID, PAYCODENAME, GRP
HAVING DATEDIFF(DAY,MIN(ABSENCEDATE), MAX(ABSENCEDATE)) >2
ORDER BY EMPLOYEEID, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),MIN(ABSENCEDATE),101)
```

I would like the output result to be:

```
6, SK, 08/15/2019, PT, 08/16/2019, NULL
10, SK, 08/16/2019, PT, 08/12/2019, 08/15/2019
14, SK, 08/12/2019, PT, 08/05/2019, 08/09/2019
23, SK, 08/02/2019, PT, 08/05/2019, 08/09/2019
```

Data set below....

```
Emp        Date            DOW    Code    Hours     Wages
6          08/15/2019      Thu    SK      8.000000  0.000000
6          08/16/2019      Fri    PT      8.000000  0.000000
10         08/12/2019      Mon    PT      8.000000  0.000000
10         08/13/2019      Tue    PT      8.000000  0.000000
10         08/14/2019      Wed    PT      8.000000  0.000000
10         08/15/2019      Thu    PT      8.000000  0.000000
10         08/16/2019      Fri    SK      8.000000  0.000000
13         08/08/2019      Thu    PT      1.000000  0.000000
13         08/09/2019      Fri    PT      2.000000  0.000000
14         08/05/2019      Mon    PT      8.000000  0.000000
14         08/06/2019      Tue    PT      8.000000  0.000000
14         08/07/2019      Wed    PT      8.000000  0.000000
14         08/08/2019      Thu    PT      8.000000  0.000000
14         08/09/2019      Fri    PT      8.000000  0.000000
14         08/12/2019      Mon    SK      8.000000  0.000000
16         08/12/2019      Mon    PT      8.000000  0.000000
16         09/06/2019      Fri    PT      3.000000  0.000000
16         09/13/2019      Fri    PT      2.000000  0.000000
21         08/05/2019      Mon    PT      8.000000  0.000000
21         08/09/2019      Fri    PT      8.000000  0.000000
21         08/16/2019      Fri    PT      8.000000  0.000000
21         09/03/2019      Tue    PT      8.000000  0.000000
21         09/04/2019      Wed    PT      8.000000  0.000000
21         09/05/2019      Thu    PT      8.000000  0.000000
23         08/02/2019      Fri    SK      8.000000  0.000000
23         08/05/2019      Mon    PT      8.000000  0.000000
23         08/06/2019      Tue    PT      8.000000  0.000000
23         08/07/2019      Wed    PT      8.000000  0.000000
23         08/08/2019      Thu    PT      8.000000  0.000000
23         08/09/2019      Fri    PT      8.000000  0.000000
```

Comment: Please show us the result that you want for this sample data.

Comment: Apologies for not including that. I'm thinking as a single record with the specifics in it.                                     EMP, SK, DATE, PT, STARTDATE, ENDDATE (or NULL if just one day)

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62075901/edit) to add this information , as tabular text (with figures that do match your sample data).

Comment: I added the output result to the original question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to create a calendar table (date dimension)  that contains all the dates and columns like dayOfTheWeek, isHoliday etc.
That will make it much easier.

Then you can use this table to join with your absence table.
e.g.

```
WITH CTE_abs
as (

    SELECT dat.theDate,allEmployees.emp,isnull(ab.code,'WD') as code,row_number() over (partition by allEmployees.emp order by dat.theDate) as seq
    FROM dbo.alldates dat
    CROSS JOIN  (   SELECT DISTINCT emp
                    FROM dbo.absences
                ) allEmployees
    LEFT JOIN dbo.absences ab
        on ab.emp = allEmployees.emp
        and ab.absenceDate = dat.theDate
    WHERE dat.theDate between '2019-08-01' and '2019-08-31'
    and dat.TheDayName not in ('sunday','saturday')

)
SELECT *
from CTE_abs abs1
join CTE_abs abs2
    on abs1.emp = abs2.emp
    and abs1.seq = abs2.seq-1
WHERE abs1.code <> abs2.code
and abs1.code in ('SK','PT')
and abs2.code in ( 'SK','PT' )
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to sort out that date table.